# WindowsService with one Time login to AD

Tags: c#, service, active-directory

I'm building a windows service using C#, that syncs AD users with a Table in Db.
usually to access AD we need to use user name and password, and to avoid saving these sensitive data, is there a way that I can validate the user and password once and then the service will be granted the access to AD permanently so it does the job with no need to re-enter the user name and password again?

Comment: Is the computer running the software joined to the AD domain that you will be querying? I believe if it is joined, the service can run as LocalSystem or NetworkService and will have access to AD based on the Computer's account. You would just remove the username/password in your code.

Comment: An alternative might be install the c# service. Then, set the service to log on as a specific domain account. This avoids having the code require a username/password when making the LDAP requests, since it will already be running under a specific account.